# add_dependencies(*_generate_messages_cpp) needed when depending on own message package?

Tags: ros, catkin-make, genmsg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, we've faced a really strange problem. We're moving message/service definitions into standalone packages, and we've faced this:

virtual_camera_msgs/CMakeLists.txt:

```
make_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(virtual_camera_msgs)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS message_generation std_msgs)

add_message_files(FILES AddRealCamera.msg VirtualCameraParameters.msg)
generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES std_msgs)

catkin_package(CATKIN_DEPENDS message_runtime std_msgs)
```

virtual_camera/CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(virtual_camera)

set(THIS_PROJECT_DEPS
  ...
  virtual_camera_msgs
)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  ${THIS_PROJECT_DEPS}
)

catkin_package(CATKIN_DEPENDS ${THIS_PROJECT_DEPS})

include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(keyboard_teleop src/keyboard_teleop.cpp)
target_link_libraries(keyboard_teleop ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

I was almost sure it is not needed to add `add_dependencies(keyboard_teleop virtual_camera_msgs_generate_messages_cpp)`, since CATKIN_DEPENDS on the whole `virtual_camera_msgs` package should automatically build all of its targets before continuing to the package that includes it.

However, if I don't add the `add_dependencies` clause, the build fails not finding `virtual_camera_msgs/AddRealCamera.h`, which should be built by the message package.

Do you know why the `generate_messages_cpp` target is not run before building the dependent package?

Using `catkin_make --use-ninja`, I've tried removing `build` and `devel` and sourcing the `setup.bash`s again.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/235035/add_dependencies(*_generate_messages_cpp)-needed-when-depending-on-own-message-package?/) by [peci1](https://answers.ros.org/users/7736/peci1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1366 on 2016-05-23

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [peci1](https://answers.ros.org/users/7736/peci1/) on 2016-05-25**:
Created an issue: https://github.com/ros/catkin/issues/801

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Got an answer in the issue. It is said to be a technical limitation of catkin. You should indeed add `add_dependencies(target catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS)` to every target that uses (any) ROS messages or other autogenerated code.

---

Originally posted by [peci1](https://answers.ros.org/users/7736/peci1/) with karma: 1366 on 2016-05-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-05-26**:\

> It is said to be a technical limitation of catkin

I think this is actually a CMake limitation, not necessarily catkin.